# Can't open IIS w3c log vb.net

Tags: vb.net, iis, streamreader, iis-logs

I have been writing an app in vb.net to copy the last few lines of an IIS W3C log file every few minusts to A file that will be used for some remote reporting.

- Everything works when I test on my local PC but when I try it on the live IIS server it tells me the file is locked by another process, I take it IIS has it locked...
- It does read in some of the sites log files (more than on site on the server) but not others, tells me locked/in use.
- Why is it that I can always open the file in notepad but not open it in my app?

The Code:

```
Dim linex = ""
Dim Line = ""

    '### IT ERROS OUT ON THE NEXT LINE ###
Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC14\u_ex130702.log")

    Do Until sr.EndOfStream
        linex = sr.ReadLine()                
         line = line & linex & vbCrLf           
    Loop

End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify correct sharing options and open mode when creating underlying `FileStream`. Since there is no constructor of `StreamReader` that passes all necessary arguments you need to construct `FileStream` first using [FileStream(String, FileMode, FileAccess, FileShare)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and than create `StreamReader` on it using [SrteamReader(Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfzs7at%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I think following should open IIS log file while it is being written to by IIS (if not - try other combinations of flags)

```
Using stream As New  New FileStream( _
 "Test#@@#.dat", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)
   Using sr As New StreamReader(stream)
```

Comment: Actually this didn't work either in my case. I'm trying also to read IIS log files to upload to a remote log analyzer, and get the same error. My stream options:
      FileMode.Open ; FileAccess.Read ; FileShare.ReadWrite ; FileOptions.SequentialScan